# Failing to reference a PDO instance set in class __construct()

Tags: php, pdo, constructor

Within the class itself, I can't seem to reference the PDO instance set in the `__construct()` function.

## Code

### Class

```
class Category {

    protected static $pdo;

    private function __construct() {
        try {
            self::$pdo = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=database', $username, $password);
            self::$pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
        }
        catch (PDOexception $e) {
            return $e->getMessage();
        }
    }

    // convert category slug to id
    public static function slug_to_id($category_slug) {

        $query = self::$pdo->prepare('SELECT id FROM `category` WHERE slug = :slug');
        $query->execute(array('slug' => $category_slug));

        $data = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
        return $data['id'];
    }
}
```

### Call

```
$id = Category::slug_to_id($category_slug);
print_r($id);
```

## Error

```
PHP Fatal error:  Call to a member function prepare() on a non-object
```

How can I make the `__construct` stuff work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way you instantiate the PDO object is the problem. You do it in the constructor, which on success should return an instance of the class `Category`, but you never call the constructor, which you really don't need since you have all static methods.
One possibility, if you insist on working with static methods, would be to instantiate the PDO object in a e.g. `init()` method.
Something like

```
class Category {

    protected static $pdo = null;

    private function init() {
        try {
            self::$pdo = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=database', $username, $password);
            self::$pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
        }
        catch (PDOexception $e) {
            return $e->getMessage();
        }

        return true;
    }

    // convert category slug to id
    public static function slug_to_id($category_slug) {

        // check whether the object's been instantiated
        if (self::$pdo === null) {
            $res = self::init();
        }

        if (is_string($res)) { 
            // an exception has been thrown
            // do something with the message you've got in $res
        }

        $query = self::$pdo->prepare('SELECT id FROM `category` WHERE slug = :slug');
        $query->execute(array(':slug' => $category_slug));

        $data = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
        return $data['id'];
    }
}
```

Also, please see the small but subtle change in the way of calling the `execute` method at the end.

Comment: You can also make your code cleaner by using the ifnull operator, `?:`, and do `$pdo = static::$instance ?: new static();` and calling the constructor that way (and several other methods; i've seen pretty much every way of making a static instance used)

Comment: I figured it was the static methods causing a problem, so I stopped using them. I like the `init()` approach though, so in case I use them in the future, I'll be sure to use that. Secondly, added the `:` in the `execute()` function. Does it matter? Anyway, thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: @Santa uhm, not really. Calling the constructor with `new static()` would return an instance of `Category` and the `$pdo` is a static field. Either take all the PDO related code into a singleton class and instantiate it properly, or do it "half-way" as I suggested...

Comment: @izolate, yes, it does matter, try binding without the `:` ;-)

Comment: @Havelock actually, in a static class you make the constructor return the static PDO instance. Every other method is static; you use method chaining and return instances from static methods to use in non-static methods. A static class `Category` can return any instance when you call `new static` and return anything you like in a custom constructor. (See laravel: DB::table($table) returns `new static($table, $args)` and returns a custom instance of a different class). It's a neater way to do it, provided you know what you are doing.